# use object key as key for another object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a type in TypeScript and use values of another object for its keys

```ts
const routes = {
  home: "HOME",
  profile: "PROFILE"
}

export type NavigatorParamList = {
  [routes.home]: undefined;
  [routes.profile]: undefined;
};
```

I know that this code is not working!
Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object's properties are variable strings and TypeScript won't let you use them as computed properties for a type unless you make them readonly literals with `as const`.

```
const routes = {
  home: "HOME",
  profile: "PROFILE"
} as const;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what [String enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) are for:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYOwrgtgBASg9mALsKBvAsAKClAEnCFAXigCJcB5AWQFFSAaLHABQCc4AzASwBtizmMCgDEAkgBk6WAL5YsAenlQwAZy4gA5lACGykFzggonKOoAmXAG5czYbTyihIUQhABGwVioBcWRAE8ABxQAOW1rDW1EOFZmbVZtCHEuFUQARigSGGAAYxizAB54JGAAOnxCKAAfWARkUrZOXmB6PTNgbhBgMwA+AG4oRTQ8ahpvNo71boHBEQkxic7pqFlMBSUY0w4ofwQoAHdtEEQoaOUVFHsHJ2hXDy9fTADgqDCIqJi4hKSUxAAmTKwXL5Ip1FqLKa9AZDVAjWjjMAgdpLMwzIRiSQIpGTLqolZyTBDTbmYDBbHHHj+AC0yMhLmA7k8Kj8QVC4S4kWisXiiWSqQAzICMNgoABtYr1CrAAC6WNpuL6TDFErKjW4fFlEIVMiAA)

```ts
enum Route {
  Home = "HOME",
  Profile = "PROFILE"
}

// using a union of individual enum members:
type NavigatorParamList1 = Record<Route.Home | Route.Profile, undefined>; // { HOME: undefined; PROFILE: undefined; }

// or if you want to use all enum members:
type NavigatorParamList2 = Record<Route, undefined>; // { HOME: undefined; PROFILE: undefined; }

// or independently-defined members
type NavigatorParamList3 = {
  [Route.Home]: undefined;
  [Route.Profile]: undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's doable with mapped types and the new `as` clause:

```
const routes = {
  home: "HOME",
  profile: "PROFILE"
} as const;

type AcceptableKeyTypes = string | number | symbol;
type ObjectWithValuesWhichCanBeKeys = {[key: AcceptableKeyTypes]: AcceptableKeyTypes};
type ValuesAsKeys<T extends ObjectWithValuesWhichCanBeKeys> = {[P in keyof T as T[P]]: unknown};

let test: ValuesAsKeys<typeof routes> = {HOME: 7, PROFILE: 4};
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4&ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiArlAphGBeGBvAUDGACxAFsUAuGAIgAkB5AWQFEqAafGABwQDMBLADYVqABQBKdAGIBJADItcAXxgBDdKEhQA3LlxQAnpxQwAgsGApOUFQCMhAaRT6AKobSYY0OHzABzGAA%20MGCIJDYocIGe%20mEgAjoGRjB0NgBWKMBQAOp8UIQAaioCiGhZhHzAhADCKmAAQiiO%20uhY2ADaANZOlGYWVrYOTq5GEAC6PeaW1naNQ24QigluMIXFaCYQTRAAPM4wKAAeqGAAJugp6Zk5easlEGUV1bUNWwB8Hu0iMD4wXfogPBgezUQLaIlG4xgiDAHTAIAA7mBFrohLBUNBKLd1psnDtEigAfAkOj3q16MxKAB2VgwcRSORMSgAFmRQA)

I'm using here a generic type: `ValuesAsKeys<T>`.

The values of T need to be constrained to types which are acceptable as keys: string | number | symbol.

the `[P in keyof T]` part is a mapped type, which iterates over all keys of T. Then, the `as` clause mapes the key to a new value, in this case to `T[P]`, which is the value of the current iterated key.

Lastly, the value is unknown, so you can use whatever new value you want. in the example I give, I'm using numbers as the new values, but it can be anything.

Note that as said in other answers, `routes` needs to have the `as const` assertion, so that the string values are considered as literal types, and can be then used as typed keys.